# How do I add uniform random noise to a timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, data-masking

I am trying to mask `datetime` values by adding uniform random noise to the `datetime` values.

I currently use the [Cape Python](https://github.com/capeprivacy/cape-python) module to add noise to my data. However I'd like to develop my own custom function similar to the one provided by Cape Python below.

```
!pip install cape-privacy
from cape_privacy.pandas.transformations import *
import datetime

s = pd.Series([datetime.date(year=2020, month=2, day=15)])
perturb = DatePerturbation(frequency="MONTH", min=-10, max=10)
perturb(s)
# Returns 2019-07-20
```

Is there a way I can add noise (between `min` and `max`) to the `DAY`, `MONTH` or `YEAR` or a combination of the aforementioned, given a datetime value and make it look credible?

```
# Input
2021-09-23

# Expected Output when noise is added to DAY between -10 and 10
2021-09-20
```

Comment: Cape Python is open source, you can [learn how DatePerturbation works](https://github.com/capeprivacy/cape-python/blob/master/cape_privacy/pandas/transformations/perturbation.py#L72)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Cape Python, so this might be off...

Here's a way to do that:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from random import randint

def date_pertubation(d, attribs, minimum, maximum):
    if isinstance(attribs, str):
        attribs = [attribs]
    attribs = [attrib.casefold() for attrib in attribs]
    year = d.year
    if "year" in attribs:
        year += randint(minimum, maximum)
    month = d.month - 1
    if "month" in attribs:
        month += randint(minimum, maximum)
        year_delta, month = divmod(month, 12)
        year += year_delta
    month += 1
    day_delta = d.day - 1
    if "day" in attribs:
        day_delta += randint(minimum, maximum)
    
    return date(year, month, 1) + timedelta(days=day_delta)
```

This

```
d = date(year=2020, month=2, day=15)
for _ in range(5):
    print(date_pertubation(d, "DAY", -20, 20).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
for _ in range(5):
    print(date_pertubation(d, "YEAR", -3, 3).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
for _ in range(5):
    print(date_pertubation(d, ["YEAR", "MONTH", "DAY"], -3, 3).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

will produce something like

```
2020-02-11
2020-02-09
2020-01-29
2020-02-29
2020-03-01

2022-02-15
2022-02-15
2020-02-15
2017-02-15
2017-02-15

2016-12-12
2016-12-14
2021-01-13
2019-11-15
2021-05-14
```